# Get Bootstrap-Slider working inside Popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I had no problem working with bootstrap-slider (http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-slider/) work using the simplest example provided on that site.  However, I was intending to use one in a bootstrap popover as part of a more extended set of settings.  The simplest example I could think of is here:

```
    <html> 
    <head>
     <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slider.css">


     <script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
     <script src="js/vendor/less-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
     <script src="js/vendor/bootstrap.js"></script>
     <script src="js/vendor/bootstrap-slider.js"></script>

     <script>
     $(function () {
          $('#rangeSlider').slider({
              formater: function(value) {
                return 'Current value: '+value;
              tooltip: 'show';
              }
     });

          $("#popoverbutton").popover({
                               html: true,
                               placement: 'bottom',
                               title: 'Options',
                               content: function(){
                                            return $("#popover-content").html();
                                        }});


           });
     </script>
     </head>

     <body>
     <h4> This is a test! </h4>
     <div class="row">
      <a href="#" id="popoverbutton" class="btn btn-inverse" rel="popover"><i class="icon-cog  icon-white"></i></a>
        </div>
     <div id="popover-content" class="hide">
         <div class="well"> Range: <input type="text" class="span2"      value="50"id="rangeSlider" data-slider-min="10" data-slider-max="100" data-slider-step="5" data-slider-value="50">
   </div>
        </div>
     </body> 
     </html>
```

As you can see, if you try to load this, it doesn't work.  The slider is rendered correctly, but cannot be interacted with, no tooltip appears, etc.

A diff between the generated html for the slider component inside and outside of a popup reveals them to be identical, so I fail to understand the holdup.  Anyone have experience with this particular issue?

Comment: Have you linked Jquery UI ?

Comment: Do you get any javascript errors?

Comment: No errors.  Included all relevant js files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to move your slider definition in the click function of the popover, so it will be fired after the static content rendering of the popover.

Code:

```
 $(function () {

     $("#popoverbutton").popover({
         html: true,
         placement: 'bottom',
         title: 'Options',
         content: function () {
             return $("#popover-content").html();
         }
     }).click(function () {
         $('#rangeSlider').slider();
     });

 });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/uTwM8/

### EDIT

I see, I think is because the popover reinit its content you can handle it manually like using `slide` event and `setValue` method.

Code:

```
var sliderVal;

$(function () {

    $("#popoverbutton").popover({
        html: true,
        placement: 'bottom',
        title: 'Options',
        content: function () {
            return $("#popover-content").html();
        }
    }).click(function () {

        $('#rangeSlider').slider().on('slide', function (ev) {
            sliderVal = ev.value;
        });
        if (sliderVal) {
            $('#rangeSlider').slider('setValue', sliderVal)
        }
    });

});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/uTwM8/2/

Comment: Okay, cool.  I am a bit dismayed that the value goes away every time the popup is hidden again.  I tried defining a $slider variable to capture the slider instantiation and replace the html in #popover-content in the click() method, but this does not work.  I am trying to understand the order these things are happening and exactly at one point I can save the slider so I can detach() it to keep the value.

Comment: Added a workaround, I can't find any alternative solution (for now)

Comment: That's basically what I ended up doing yesterday. I am accepting as the answer.